# coarser than triangulations "almost partitions" into simplices

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, polyhedra, simplicial-complexes

The total space $T$ of an embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ pure $n$-dimensional simplicial complex (in other words, the union of finitely many $n$-dimensional compact convex polytopes) sometimes admits an "almost partition" into $n$-simplices (i.e. $T$ equals the union of these simplices, and the interiors of these simplices do not, pairwise, intersect)  which is coarser than a triangulation.

For instance, consider the union $T$ of two tetrahedra $T_1$, $T_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which intersect at the mid-point $M=E_1\cap E_2$ of edges $E_i\in T_i$, $1\leq i\leq 2$. Then any triangulation of $T$ will have to include $M$, and have at least 4 simplices. On the other hand, there exist an obvious "almost partition" of $T$ into just 2 simplices, $T_1$ and $T_2$.

We wonder whether there exists any research on these kinds of "almost partitions", and whether there is any well-established terminology here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "triangulation" tends to be ambiguous, as they appear both in a geometric and topological context.  In this case, what you want is called a *dissection*, at least in the discrete geometry literature (see e.g. [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm) and [there](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-3-642-12970-4)).

P.S.  Oh, yes, plenty of research.  See e.g. [here](http://www-m10.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/Lehrstuhl/PublikationenJRG/30_SimplicialDissecions.pdf) for whether dissections of convex polytopes can be smaller than triangulations.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very useful. Especially the fact that two dissections are connected by elementary moves (unlike triangulations) is simplifying our problems a lot.

Are there any plans for your book to be published?
